# How to save Sessions in Ruby on rails using haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am relatively new to ruby on rails! I would like some help in saving my checkbox preferences so that upon selection my previous settings are saved.. 
My controller.rb looks as shown below!

```
def index
    if params[:ratings].present?    
      @movies = Movie.where(rating: params[:ratings].keys)
    else         
      @movies = Movie.all(:order => "title xxx, release_date xxx")
      if params[:sort_by] == 'xxxx'
        @title_header = 'xxxx'
      elsif params[:sort_by] == 'xxxx'
        @release_header ='xxxxx'
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: `Movie.all(:order...)` should be `Movie.order(...).load` in modern Rails.

Comment: I see no difference between if and elsif condition clauses.

Comment: Hi tadman, My code works fine with movie.all,though I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the value in the params in session. You can read more about sessions in [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session).

```
def index
    if params[:ratings].present?    
      @movies = Movie.where(rating: params[:ratings].keys)
    else         
      @movies = Movie.all(:order => "title xxx, release_date xxx")
      if params[:sort_by] == 'xxxx'
        @title_header = 'xxxx'
      elsif params[:sort_by] == 'xxxx'
        @release_header ='xxxxx'
    end
    session[:current_sort_by] = params[:sort_by]
  end  
end
```

Comment: Hi Nishu, I truly appreciate your getting back to me... however that code didnt work!!

Comment: can you provide more details on requirements.

Comment: if the user has selects any combination of column sorting and restrict-by-rating constraints, and then the user clicks to see the details of one of the movies (for example), when she clicks the Back to Movie List on the detail page, the movie listing should “remember” the user’s sorting and filtering settings from before.
 you can selectively apply the settings from the session[] even if the incoming URI doesn’t have the appropriate params[] set.

Comment: Nishu, I replaced, session[:current_sort_by] = params[:sort_by] with session[:rating_sort_by] = params[:sort_by], it partially worked, remembered the check-box preferences but didn’t remember the movie sort order! So this a step towards the right direction!!

Comment: Any idea how changing a key name in hash worked? You need to fetch value from session with same key at the time of rendering.

Comment: Ok will try.. Though I am not exactly sure what key value I have to fetch @ rendering!! That documentation that you previously attached to message didnt really help on how to best use sessions in rails..